# PDO_firebird can't execute prepare statement with integer parameters

Tags: pdo, firebird

I've got problem with some query execution with PDO_firebird on PHP server.
On 2 of my server, when I execute the code below, I get an error.

```
$sth=$dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myField= ?');
$sth->execute(array(10));
```

The error:

> Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -303 arithmetic exception, numeric
> overflow, or string truncation.

This error is present only from one PHP server, the other server PHP that connect to the same Firebird 2.5 server doesn't have this problem.
The problem appears only when I try to filter on integer field.
Any idea?

Comment: What is the type of myField? Which version of the Firebird client library do you use on those servers, do they match?

Comment: `only when I try to filter on integer field` any integer field or ony `myfield` ? if you would not filter - what value has the top row in that column? would error appear if you make filtering on that very value and only read that very row ( `select first(1) * from ...`)? May it be that the error is triggered when a single row is returned or when no data at all (`select * ... where 2 = 3`) ? Would error persist if instead of `*` you would specifcy only one column? May be only a specific column or some columns trigger the error? Use FBProfiler to trace real requests between your app and Firebird